# py4j.Py4JException: Method set([class java.lang.String, class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist in Databricks

Tags: java, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to access a remote S3 bucket using Databricks.

From what I have understood, this is what my code should look like,

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_access_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")


df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header",True).load('s3a://bucket/path/to/file.csv')

df.show()
```

I seem to be getting the following error when trying to set the Spark configurations,

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o371.set. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method set([class java.lang.String, class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:341)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:349)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:286)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration with S3 as per the [official document](https://docs.databricks.com/storage/amazon-s3.html#access-s3-buckets-with-uris-and-aws-keys):

```
Access_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Scope_name", key = "aws_access_key")
Secret_key = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "Scope_name", key = "aws_secret_key")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", Access_key)
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", Secret_key)

region = "aws-region-id"
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3." + region + ".amazonaws.com")

conn = sc.textFile("s3a://%s/.../..." % aws_bucket_name)
conn.count()
```

**Or**

You can try this alternative approach [Mounting AWS S3 buckets on Databricks](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/readwrite-mount-from-aws-s3-databricks-deepak-rajak) by Deepak Rajak

Comment: This does not solve the problem. The error is that I am getting is that the `.set()` does not seem to exist.

Comment: well clearly the set() call with the type of the arguments being passed in *doesn't exist*. Pass down datatypes which are supported.